# JSF + Primefaces: Ajax CRUD-Actions in Master-Detail-View only work once per page-load

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Mojarra 2.0.3 on JBoss AS 6 with Primefaces 2.2.1 + Hibernate.

I've got a master-detail-view with p:datatable and p:dialog for Person (prename, lastname).

Code of Person.java:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 279906432340876832L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String prename;
private String lastname;

    // getter and setter...
}
```

With a "create"-button a new instance can be created, with the "edit"-button, a selected item can be edited.

Code of .xhtml:

```
<h:form id="personForm">

    <!-- 2 Buttons to open create/edit Dialog -->
    <p:panel id="tableButtons">
        <p:commandButton value="create" action="#{personBean.showCreateView}"
            update="personForm:detailPanel" oncomplete="personDialog.show()" />
        <p:commandButton value="edit" action="#{personBean.showEditView}"
            update="personForm:detailPanel" oncomplete="personDialog.show()"
            rendered="#{personBean.rowSelected}" />
    </p:panel>

    <!--  DataTable for list-View -->
    <p:dataTable var="item" styleClass="table"
        value="#{personBean.personList}" id="personTable" paginator="true"
        selectionMode="single" selection="#{personBean.selectedPerson}"
        rowSelectListener="#{personBean.select}"
        onRowSelectUpdate="personForm:tableButtons"
        rowUnselectListener="#{personBean.unselect}"
        onRowUnselectUpdate="personForm:tableButtons" rows="10">
        <p:column sortBy="#{item.prename}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="prename" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.prename}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{item.lastname}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="lastname" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.lastname}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <!--  Dialog for detailed-View -->
    <p:dialog id="personDialog" widgetVar="personDialog">
        <p:panel id="detailPanel">
            <h:panelGrid cellpadding="4">
                <h:outputText value="prename: " />
                <h:inputText value="#{personBean.selectedPerson.prename}" />
                <h:outputText value="lastname: " />
                <h:inputText value="#{personBean.selectedPerson.lastname}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="persist"
                actionListener="#{personBean.persist}"
                rendered="#{personBean.createView}" update="personForm"
                oncomplete="personDialog.hide()" />
            <p:commandButton value="save" actionListener="#{personBean.merge}"
                update="personForm" rendered="#{personBean.editView}"
                oncomplete="personDialog.hide()" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

The managedBean holds 2 boolean attributes createView/editView which appear in the render-attribute of the dialogs commandbuttons, a List for the DataTable, "selectedPerson" for Detail-View and another boolean to trigger edit-Button in case of row-selection in the DataTable.

Code of Managed-Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "personBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonMBean {

private List<Person> personList;
private Person selectedPerson;

// row in the table has been selected
private boolean rowSelected;

// only render the active View
private boolean createView;
private boolean editView;
// ... displayView and more possible

@EJB
private CRUDService crudService;

public PersonMBean() {
    personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    selectedPerson = new Person();
}

// CRUD-options
public String persist(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    crudService.persist(selectedPerson);
    return null;
}
public String merge(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    selectedPerson = crudService.merge(selectedPerson);
    return null;
}

// switch between Views
public String showCreateView() {
    selectedPerson = new Person();
    createView = true;
    editView = false;
    return null;
}
public String showEditView() {
    createView = false;
    editView = true;
    return null;
}

public List<Person> getPersonList() {
    return crudService.getAllPerson();
}

public Person getSelectedPerson() {
    if (selectedPerson == null) {
        selectedPerson = new Person();
    }
    return selectedPerson;
}

public String select(SelectEvent event) {
    setRowSelected(true);
    return null;
}

public String unselect(UnselectEvent event) {
    setRowSelected(false);
    return null;
}

// getter + setter
public void setPersonList(List<Person> personList) {this.personList = personList;}
public void setSelectedPerson(Person selectedPerson) {this.selectedPerson = selectedPerson;}
public boolean isRowSelected() {return rowSelected;}
public void setRowSelected(boolean rowSelected) {this.rowSelected = rowSelected;}
public void setCreateView(boolean createView) {this.createView = createView;}
public boolean isCreateView() {return createView;}
public void setEditView(boolean editView) {this.editView = editView;}
public boolean isEditView() {return editView;}

}
```

The problem is that while a single create/edit Person is successfull, after that a create-Action inserts an empty row and an edit-Action inserts a row with wrong values. When I reload the page, again the first action is ok, the second one fails... :(

I suppose that the PersonMBean.selectedPerson has got an obsolete state but I can not figure it out nor can I find a solution to solve it.

p.s. crudService just calls em.persist + em.merge

Code of CRUDService:

```
@Stateless
public class CRUDService {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public <T> T persist(T t) {
    this.em.persist(t);
    return t;
}

public <T> T merge(T t) {
    return this.em.merge(t);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
    Query q = em.createQuery("from Person");
    return q.getResultList();
}
}
```

The web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID"
version="3.0">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm really struggling on this one, hope you can help me.

If anything is wrong with formatting / style please let me know so I can update it.

Comment: you don't need to do this.em.flush(); and    this.em.refresh(t);. The Stateless EJB manages transactions automatically, in this case it will start a Transaction when persist method is called and commit it when that method returns.

Comment: thx, I've fixed it, didnt solve the problem though

Comment: @katana0815 what was the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.jaxio.com/en/celerio.html it outputs JSF + Primefaces master/detail pages that can be used as an example

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to your web.xml then rerun your code ?

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
```

Comment: I've added it to web.xml but it had no effect.